# Algebraic independece of modular forms for Fricke group over $\mathbb C(q)$

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms, automorphic-forms, transcendental-number-theory

Let $q=e^{\pi i \tau}$ for $\tau \in \mathbb H$ and 
$$
P_2(q)=\frac{P(q)+2P(q^2)}{3}, \quad Q_2(q)=\frac{Q(q)+4Q(q^2)}{5}, \\ R_2(q)=\frac{R(q)+8R(q^2)}{9},
$$
a Fourier series of quasi-modular form or modular forms for the Fricke group $\Gamma_0^+(2)$.

In 'W. Zudilin, "[The hypergeometric equation and Ramanujan functions](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023%2FB%3ARAMA.0000012426.23921.24)", Ramanujan J. 7:4 (2003), 435–447' ([MSN](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2040982)), Proposition 6 (and similarly in Proposition 7), he said that the function $P_2,Q_2,R_2$ are algebarically independent over $\mathbb C(q)$.

He mention that (table in p445) 
$$
P_2=3y_2+3y_1+2y_2 \\
Q_2=(y_0-y_1)(y_2-y_1) \\
R_2=(y_0-y_1)^2(y_2-y_1),
$$
and Corollary 2 says that the transcendence degree over $\mathbb C$ of $\mathbb C(\tau, y_0(\tau), y_1(\tau), y_2(\tau))$ is 4. From this, we know that $P_2,Q_2,R_2$ are algebraically independent over $\mathbb C$.

But how we know over $\mathbb C(q)$?